# HTTPS call via HttpClient Getting 404 - NOT FOUND

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've been going crazy over this particular problem. What I am trying to do is make an HTTPS Call to the server after a user clicks the sign up button. The server must add the new user to the database and send me back a user key. I've tested the httpClient class with a local LAMP server without HTTPS. Works fine. When I try to connect to the productions  server with SSL I GET A 404 - NOT FOUND. I have double checked that the URL, CONTENT and Authorization is formatted well. As a matter of facted I codded it in a console application and it connects to the production server every time. It just does not work with the windows phone emulator or my windows phone. Been monitoring everything with fiddler. I've also used the WebClient class to no avail. PLEASE HELP!

Code below!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JailBird_ProtoType.Models
{
   // CLASS USED TO FORMAT OBJECT TO JSON STRING
    public class TestUser
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { set; get; }
        public List<string> Roles = new List<string>();
    }
}

using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace JailBird_ProtoType.Services
{
    public class UploadJsonService
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        public BackgroundWorker GetBackGroundWorker { get { return bw; } }

        private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private HttpClient GetClient { get { return client; } }

        private HttpResponseMessage response;
        public HttpResponseMessage GetResponseMessage { get { return response; } }

        // SET THE UPLOAD URL
        private string uploadURL;
        public string SetUploadURL { set { uploadURL = value; } }

        // SET THE STRING DATA UPLOAD VALUE
        private string jsonValue ="";
        public string SetJsonValue { set { jsonValue = value; } }

        private HttpContent httpContent;
        public HttpContent GetHttpContent { get { return httpContent; } set { httpContent = value; } }

        // SET THE METHOD TYPE UPLOAD VALUE
        private string Method = "POST";
        public string SetMethod { set { Method = value; } }


        // CONSRUCTOR
       public UploadJsonService()
        {
            SetUpClass();
        }

        public UploadJsonService(string url, string data)
        {
            SetUploadURL = url;
            SetJsonValue = data;
            SetUpClass();
        }

        public UploadJsonService(string url, string method, string data)
        {
            SetUploadURL = url;
            SetJsonValue = data;
            SetMethod = method;
            SetUpClass();
        }


        private void SetUpClass()
        {
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);

            httpContent = new StringContent(jsonValue);
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        }


        public void StartUpload()
        {
            try
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // RUN BACKGROUND WORKER
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        public void CancelUpload()
        {
            // CANCEL ALL WORKER TASKS
            try
            {
                client.Dispose();
                httpContent = null;
                bw.CancelAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        public void SetHeader(string header, string value)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header, value);
        }

        private async void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            if (isConnectionReady())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Method.ToLower() == "post")
                    {
                        response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uploadURL, UriKind.Absolute), httpContent);
                    }
                    else if (Method.ToLower() == "push")
                    {
                        response = await client.PutAsync(new Uri(uploadURL, UriKind.Absolute), httpContent);
                    }


                    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESPONSE HERE


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    //UPDATE THE UI THREAD HERE
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Upload did not complete successfully. Check your connection settings.", "Something Went Wrong", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    }));
                }


            }
            else
            {
                //UPDATE THE UI THREAD HERE
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Check your phone's connection settings", "No Network Connection", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }));
            }
        }


        // METHOD USED TO CHECK FOR NETWORK CONNECTION
        private bool isConnectionReady()
        {
            bool internet = false;

            //Check if network is available
            if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
            {
                internet = true;
            }

            return internet;
        }

    }
}

// THIS METHOD IS ACTIVATED IN THE SIGNUP BUTTON EVENT HANDLER
public void SendToServer()
{
          //  string user = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.Users[0]); // Get User Information 

            TestUser me = new TestUser() { Name="testName2", Password="password",Email="mail@mail.com"};
            me.Roles.Add("User");
            string meString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(me);

            if (App.Settings.Contains("FirstSignUp"))
            {
                service = new UploadJsonService(ConnectToServer.USER_UPLOAD_URL,"PUT",meString);
            }
            else
            {
                service = new UploadJsonService(ConnectToServer.USER_UPLOAD_URL,"POST",meString);
            }

            service.SetHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + ConnectToServer.Get64BitEncoding(ConnectToServer.SERVER_ADMIN));

            service.GetBackGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(RunWorkerServiceCompleted);
            service.StartUpload();
}

 private void RunWorkerServiceCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 // DO WORK AFTER THE BACKGROUND WORKER COMPLETES
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JailBird_ProtoType.Services
{
    // THIS CLASS HOLDS ALL SERVER INFORMATION
    // FOR QUICK ACCESS AND CHANGE
    public static class ConnectToServer
    {
        public static string SERVER_ADMIN = "admin:password";

        // UPLOAD USER TO DB

        public static string USER_UPLOAD_URL = "https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:443/api/users";




        public static string Get64BitEncoding(string key) {
            byte[] convert = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(convert);
        }
    }
}
```

omitted real server address for security reasons.

Sorry my code is not structured Right. Been changing it around to get this to work.

Comment: First thing: Is the SSL verified? And secondly please install fiddler and check the packages. Something's might be wrong - just debuggin and double checking the code wont help you.

Comment: As George Nikolaides hinted, Windows Phone only accepts HTTPS connections with a trusted certificate. Make sure the certificate used by the production server hasn't expired and matches your domain name. If it's self-signed, you need to install it manually on your phone.

Comment: I will try the suggestions and update this post with results. Thanks.